# i need to find the maximum and miinimum average salarying paying university

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data set like this .

```
Sector   Salary Paid Employer        Job Title  
College $105,595.39 Algonquin College   Professor   
university $208,456,897, harvard university Professor
 College    $200,000,000 csi College    Professor   
university $50,000, ISU university Professor
  College   $60,000.39 Algonquin College    Professor   
university $258,645,789, ALU university Professor
```

I am trying to groupby based in the seector i.e. college or universityI have grouped by by like

```
universities = df[ df['Employer'].str.contains('Univ',regex=True) ]
university_group= universities.groupby('Employer').
```

After this i try to find the average of every individual university

```
average_salary_university=university_group['Salary ($)'].agg(np.mean)
```

This give the individual average salary of university. I am trying to find the lowest and highest average salary of a university from a list.  and For each, how many employees do they have making over $100,000CAN?

I try to this

```
minimum= (average_salary_university).values.argmax()
df[df[minimum]]
```

But it is not working. 
Can somebody help me please

Comment: Could you paste a larger sample of the dataframe and expected output?

Comment: i have added the input.  Regrading the output i need to find a name of a university that has a lowest average salary among others

Answer (score 0):

Use [idxmin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) to get the minimum index value, since the university is in the index after groupby and agg

```py
min_uni = average_salary_university.idxmin()
print(min_uni)
# ISU University
```

Note: Please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for good reproducible pandas example. It would be much easier if you could provide the dataframe like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Sector', 'Salary Paid', 'Employer', 'Job Title'],
                  data=[['College', '$105,595.39', 'Algonquin College', 'Professor'],
                        ['University', '$208,456,897', 'harvard University', 'Professor'],
                        ['College', '$200,000,000', 'csi College', 'Professor'],
                        ['University', '$50,000', 'ISU University', 'Professor'],
                        ['College', '$60,000.39', 'Algonquin College', 'Professor'],
                        ['University', '$258,645,789', 'ALU University', 'Professor']
                        ])
```